# Sharing Session between a Spring Boot application and PHP using Redis

Tags: java, php, spring-boot, redis, spring-session

We have a lot of pages which are already running in PHP (core) and require very frequent (and sudden) changes. Therefore we would not like to migrate our code base entirely to Java. I was trying to create an architecture where we could have some part of the business logic processing (which requires a stronger foundation) in Spring Boot and the rest (especially the reporting part) to remain in PHP.

Now for this, I want to be able to share the Session between the already existing PHP applications and the application I am currently writing in Spring Boot. I have configured this application to run with Spring Session using Redis. I cannot and do not want to use a table based implementation for session management owing to a limited amount of resources in our database server.

My configuration for using Redis with Spring Spring Boot is as follows:

```
spring.session.store-type=redis
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.password=#somepasswordhere
spring.redis.port=6379
server.servlet.session.timeout=20m
spring.session.redis.flush-mode=on_save
spring.session.redis.namespace=SPRING_SESSION

spring.redis.jedis.pool.max-active=8
spring.redis.jedis.pool.max-idle=8
spring.redis.jedis.pool.max-wait=-1
spring.redis.jedis.pool.min-idle=16
spring.redis.timeout=1s
```

I have also been able to configure PHP to use the Redis server as it's data store for session management.

I would like to know if there is any way where I can have a common session for the two, i.e. where one application in PHP can access values (and its other properties such as expiry/validity) set to the session by the other application in Spring Boot and vice versa?

Also, I know that it would be off topic, but any suggestions for a more efficient Redis configuration would also be appreciated here for the Spring Session part.

Comment: Did you find answer for this ?